# Google Cloud EndPoint in Java calling from Angular 2 (Angular-cli) with Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-endpoints

i am using in the Front End: Angular 2 and i have a Google Cloud EndPoint in Java, i don't now how to call my methods from angular 2, beacuse in the examples from [1]: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-javascript is with angular 1, and don't pase any code because the example is in the oficial page, some one that give the specific way to make this please from angular 2 whit @angular/cli and typescript call to my method in the Google Cloud EndPoint.

Answer (score 0):

The example link that you gave is Angular agnostic and is not specifically for Angular 1. That particular example waits for gapi to load, loads the appropriate API, then makes a call to the API. You should be able to use this flow for Angular 1 or 2.